# I can't deploy app on remote server by `docker compose` from local machine (problem with SSH)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

1. I have some app on local machine (Ubuntu 20.04) with `compose.yaml` file. Executing `docker compose up`  works fine - service deploy on local system.
2. I have remote server (Ubuntu 22.04) with docker engine installed and I would like to deploy my app on remote server.
3. I've changed `DOCKER_HOST` to `ssh:user//X.X.X.X` and run `docker compose up` again. But error ...`ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory` ... `Permission denied (publickey,password).` received every run.
4. I installed `ssh-askpass`, but many many GUI prompts for entering password are opened after `docker compose up` without any result.

How should I configure system to deploy app on remote server from local machine by docker compose?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

Problem was in SSH settings - I didn't configure it properly. After I sent my .pub key to server all have work fine!